# UIScrollview frozen when search bar in use

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uisearchbar

I have a Controller with a search bar at top, and when the user types, autocompleted search results are shown below it, in a UIScrollView.

Problem:
The results show up, but the user can't scroll those results. The scrollview is frozen. The only way to scroll is to push 'Cancel' in the Search bar. Tapping "Search" hides the keyboard, but even then the scrollview is frozen.

Desired:
As the user is typing, search results are being autocompleted. At any given time, the user can *scroll* through those results. They should not have to hit Cancel in order to scroll.

There are more results than will fit on the screen so this isn't an issue of content being only slightly larger than the screen.

Nothing special in CancelButtonClicked or SearchButtonClicked:

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {    
   searchBar.text = @"";
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fetchSearchResult:) toTarget:self withObject:searchBar.text];    
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

if([searchBar.text length] >=3){
    [mySpinner startAnimating];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fetchSearchResult:) toTarget:self withObject:searchBar.text]; 

}
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
// This occurs when user starts entering text
// We want to keep the background area dark

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had possibly the same issue: UISearchBar was nested into UIScrollView, so when search results was shown- It was impossible to scroll parent view.
..I was puzzled but I learned ([UISearchDisplayCtrl private api](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UISearchDisplayController2.h)) that UISearchDisplayController locks all parent scroll views (bitch).

So U should add category UISearchDisplayController+Custom:

```
@implementation UISearchDisplayController (Custom)

- (void)_disableParentScrollViews {
}

- (void)_enableParentScrollViews {
}

@end
```